# CoffeeScript comments in JavaScript output

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there out any flag in the CoffeeScript compiler to add single-line coffee comments to Javascript output? I read some time ago it would be supported but it turns out this option still remains unavailable.

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: If all the comments gets dropped away, generated js is only half worth of its original. Also people who are not familiar with cs reading generated code without single line comments is much harder.

Comment: Are you worried about debugging the generated JS code in the browser?

Comment: @Chandranshu I've seen at least one JS library that's written in CoffeeScript, but the downloads are Javascript to make things easier for users. It makes perfect sense to ship commented Javascript for debugging purposes in that case. The same thing applies on a team that doesn't standardise on CoffeeScript - the people who like it will use it to author scripts but should ultimately put Javascript into the codebase as well. If it's an uncommented blob it makes it harder to trace script bugs, and if you used source maps only the people familiar with Coffee could do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest option is just to use block comments everywhere. A search/replace across your code base could take care of this in a trivially short time. You would change

```
# coffeescript one-line comment, not passed through to js
```

into this

```
### coffeescript block comment, which IS passed through to js ###
```

A harder option would be to mod coffeescript itself. For instance, the [coffeescript lexer](https://coffeescript.org/annotated-source/lexer.html#section-20) is very well documented, and shows that the logic used to identify block comments. By carefully modifying the lexer, I imagine you could convince it that your single line comments were block comments, which again, are already passed through to js. I haven't tried this, however.

Comment: @jarandaf do you mind posting what you changed the regex to if that's the route you went?

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single line comment by making it plain JS, eg.

```
`// this will appear in the compiled JS`
```

Whether you should or not is a separate question :)